# will completeAdding to wake up the thread already blocked by take

Tags: c#, .net

in the case that the consumer is already blocked by take() , will producer's completeAdding wake it up? using BlockingCollection. MSDN does not state it clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

A quick experiment shows it will throw an InvalidOperation exception in the Take() method.

And that makes sense:

```
int value = data.Take();
```

What would `value` be when the Thread/Task would just 'wake up' without any data to return ?

If you are blocked with  `TryTake(out x)` it will return with `false` when  Adding is completed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with BlockingCollections, but in general my understanding is that if something is blocked it does not get "woken up" by a third party.